# LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end

Tags: math-mode

My question is very simple: what is the problem with the following code?

```
\begin{proof}
Let $N = (Q, \sum, \delta, q_0, F)$ be the NFA recognising some language $A$. We construct a DFA $M = (Q_1, \sum, \delta_1, q_1, F_1)$ recognising $A$. Before doing that full construction, let's first consider the easier case wherein $N$ has no $\epsilon$ arrows. Later, we take the $\epsilon$ arrows into account.
\begin{enumerate}
\item $Q' = \mathcal{P}(Q)$, i.e. every state of $M$ is a set of states of $N$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
```

Note that I was able before this proof environment to use everything that I am using within it...

I have spent half an hour trying to figure out what is the problem, it seems that there's someone kidding me, and that doesn't let me work, when I just have a few hours to finish this.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably have defined yourself a `proof` environment. Without more details, it's impossible to say. The error is surely due to a misplaced ``\\`` that is not in the shown code, so it must be in the definition of `proof`.

Comment: using `\\ ` that way (apart from producing the referenced error) removes all the features of normal latex headings, you could get a page break the line after Proof, or just before \qed, blank lines within the environment have weird effects (the problem here). Also this shows why the question should always have a complete example document that shows the error.

Comment: Why isn't anyone telling the OP about the importance of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) ... ?

Comment: @Sverre David did :)

Answer (score 7):

The redefinition you give of the `proof` environment is *very* wrong and it's better to stick with the `amsmath` one.

If you don't like the keyword “Proof” to be in italics and prefer boldface italic (I wouldn't), you can do it quite easily:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\bfseries\itshape}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Let $N = (Q, \sum, \delta, q_0, F)$ be the NFA recognising some language $A$. We construct a DFA $M =
(Q_1, \sum, \delta_1, q_1, F_1)$ recognising $A$. Before doing that full construction, let's first
consider the easier case wherein $N$ has no $\epsilon$ arrows. Later, we take the $\epsilon$ arrows
into account.
\begin{enumerate}
\item $Q' = \mathcal{P}(Q)$, i.e. every state of $M$ is a set of states of $N$.
\item $Q' = \mathcal{P}(Q)$, i.e. every state of $M$ is a set of states of $N$.\qedhere
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

Text following the proof will be separated from the proof.

\end{document}
```

Note that when a proof ends with a list environment or a display, you should help LaTeX by issuing `\qedhere`, which is not needed otherwise.

[image]

If you want a black tombstone, just add

```
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
```

and load `amssymb`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\bfseries\itshape}{}{}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Let $N = (Q, \sum, \delta, q_0, F)$ be the NFA recognising some language $A$. We construct a DFA $M = 
(Q_1, \sum, \delta_1, q_1, F_1)$ recognising $A$. Before doing that full construction, let's first 
consider the easier case wherein $N$ has no $\epsilon$ arrows. Later, we take the $\epsilon$ arrows 
into account.
\begin{enumerate}
\item $Q' = \mathcal{P}(Q)$, i.e. every state of $M$ is a set of states of $N$.
\item $Q' = \mathcal{P}(Q)$, i.e. every state of $M$ is a set of states of $N$.\qedhere
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

Text following the proof will be separated from the proof.

\end{document}
```

[image]